# Binding WPF Datagrid to Navigation Property EF?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, wpfdatagrid

I want to bind a Datagrid to navigation property.

for example.If I have two entities Clients and phones linked by Client_ID

No problem when user edit phone details,modification is saved correctly

the problem exist when users add new Phone and save,the new row is not saved.
also If user add new client. client data is saved but all phones are not saved? 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void Save_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Client1.PhoneNumbers.ToList().ForEach(pn => pn.Client = Client1);
        Client1.OtherNavigationProperties = null;
        using(var context=new MyContext())
        {
            if (insert)
                context.Client.Add(Client1);
            if (update)
            {
                var client = context.GetClientsByClientID(Client1.ID);
                client.PhoneNumbers = Client1.PhoneNumbers;
                //other changes if any in client
                //again set all navigation properties null else than PhoneNumbers

            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

this might be because Phone will have the Property Client When you add Phone then this property is null, so You will also have to set its Client Property to the Current client or more exactly the client whose id is going to be in Phone F.K . Hope this will help.

```
public void SaveClient(Client client)
        {
            client.PhoneNumbers.ToList().ForEach(pn=>pn.Client=client);
            using(var context=new MyContext())
            {
                  context.Clients.Add(client);
                  context.SaveChanges();
             }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks For Reply. I deleted the client property from Phone. But it didn't work

Comment: No you can't delete it then it will not work ,All you need to do is to set the client to it when you send it for save or when you initialize Phone object.

Comment: Users add new phone from WPF Datagrid. Could you tell me which datagrid event should I use to set the client to phone. I'll appreciate if you could provide code sample.

Comment: just do that when you send the Client to save from ViewModel or you can do that in DAL/Repository . Just before saving the client.

Comment: User might add as many phone as they like also ther are a lot of detailed table linked to the client and have the same problem.I don't know a lot about Dal/Repository Pattern.

Comment: set them null like client.DetailedTable=null before you send to save if you dont want any change in it. Set all Navigation Properties of Client =null else than Phone

Comment: i made the change above that exception will not come nw

Comment: _client.Phones.ToList().ForEach(pn=>pn.Client=_client); ef.Clients.Add(_client); ef.SaveChanges(); still not saving phones